# Azure SQL Data Sync from SQL Azure to On-Premise SQL Server

Tags: azure, synchronization, azure-sql-database

I have a table in which 10000 records are there. I am trying to do the synchronization between SQL Azure to on-premise SQL Server using Azure Data Sync Tool. The sync tool is taking 35 minutes to sync all the records. When I update some records in the table and sync again, it again taking 35 minutes to sync. As Per my knowledge, sync tool should only sync the updated records, not all.
Please help.

Comment: Just out of interest, are you using this as a backup strategy?

Comment: is this Azure SQL Data Sync Service on Azure? what does the log say on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is for backup and also we are doing synchronization with on premises SQL to on premises Oracle and vice versa ie.
Sync between

SQL Azure <=> on premises SQL Server <=> on premises Oracle

Comment: how do you sync between oracle and SQL server... it seems like Azure Data Sync only works with MS SQL Server, right?